# Obtener todo los datos de una tabla dependiendo del select option

Tags: php, mysql

tengo ese codigo en php mysql

```
    include('conectar.ini.php');

$base = "SELECT * FROM viajes ORDER BY id_viaje ASC";
$nquery = mysqli_query($conn, $base);
$id_viaje = (!empty ($_GET['id_viaje']) ) ? $_GET['id_viaje'] : NULL; 
$fechaida = isset($_POST['fechaida']) ? $_POST['fechaida'] : NULL;
//SELECT CON LOS MOTIVOS DEL VIAJE
echo "<label for='viaje' class='form-label'><strong>ELIJA EL VIAJE</strong></label>";
echo "<select class='form-select' name='id_viaje' id='viaje' required>";
echo "<option value='' disabled selected hidden></option>";
while($crow = mysqli_fetch_array($nquery)){
    $fechaida = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($crow['fechaida']));
    echo "<option value='".$crow['id_viaje']."' data-fecha='".$fechaida."'>".$crow['motivo']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Me gustaría que al seleccionar el en select el motivo del viaje por ejemplo "Vacaciones" me muestre todas las personas que viajan por vacaciones eso en la misma pagina.
Alguien que ya ha echo o sabe si se puede? Gracias de antemano

Comment: No estoy seguro si entiendo lo que querés, pero podes hacero con jquery y ajax, así podes tener un "select dinámico".

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama *select dependientes*, el caso más típico es cuando eliges una provincia y en base a esa provincia te salen todas las ciudades. Para hacerlo en una misma página tendrás que usar Ajax, como indica @RicardoPortillo, o bien la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. En un `select` tendrías todos los motivos de viaje, escucharías los cambios en ese `select`, mandando el valor seleccionado vía Ajax o Fetch para operar una consulta del tipo `SELECT * FROM laTabla WHERE motivo='elMotivoSeleccionado'`. Es relativamente simple de lograr, revisa preguntas aquí mismo.

Comment: Buen dia, sisi, eso seria, sabes donde puedo ver un ejemplo?